# What does "object affine" mean?

Tags: terminology

What does "object affine" mean? For instance, there are object affine thread pools. While I understand both thread pools and affine transformations in math, I can't think of an association between them.

Comment: Google said "`No results found for "object affine thread pools".`"

Comment: @KennyTM - you should totally drop what you're doing on Google and use jQuery :)

Comment: @KennyTM: this question is the top hit now for that query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you thinking about [Affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation)?  If so I suggest that what it means with respect to threads, is that the certain threads will be linked to a cetain set of resources like for exmample a cpu or a core perhaps, and not be swtched across to another set of resources. This can allow for certain low level optimisations such as maximising L1 cache hits